# perl reading each line in a file using $_ not working

Tags: perl

I am reading 'Beginning Perl: Online book by Simon Cozen'. In my code below, print comment prints all lines of my data.txt file. But my while loop does not print anything. Please help me fix this problem.

```
open(FILE,'data.txt');
my $line = <FILE>;
my @lines = <FILE>;
print @lines;

while (<FILE>) {
    print "$_";
}
```

Comment: Note that you should use the 3-arg `open`, perform an error check, and use a lexical file handle instead of a bareword one: `open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've read the file and now you're "at the end", you need to close the file and open it again to get back to the start.

Alternatively, use `seek FILE, 0, SEEK_SET;` on the open file to reset back to the start without a close and reopen. (Use `use Fcntl qw( SEEK_SET );` to import `SEEK_SET`.)

Comment: You can also do `seek $fh, 0, 0;` to get the same effect.

Comment: @stevieb, Sure, you could replace the meaningful constant with an obscure magical number instead, but that would be silly.

Comment: Original answer had `seek FILE, 0, 0;`, it has been edited a couple of times since. I know "0, 0" worked since then I think we've had `SEEK_CUR` (which sounds to me like "current"? and now `SEEK_SET` This question ,ay be interesting reading (it was for me) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556332/perl-seek-function