# Read n bytes of text from file

Tags: file, perl, byte, buffer

I have a text file, I read first line from it to find out how many bytes does it take,

```
open($fh, "<:raw", $file);
my $len;
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  $len = length $row;
  last;
};
```

Now I want to read that file from mid row +100 bytes, how do I do that?

Something like

```
read ($fh, 100, $len/2)
```

Cannot really figure out the proper syntax.

Comment: Do you by "_from midrow_" mean from the middle of the first row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl seek function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556332/perl-seek-function)

Comment: Yes, I want to half the first row in bytes

Comment: OK, so that's 100 bytes after the half of the first line ... then what?

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear, i want to "read", that is get the string from byte x to byte y from the file.

Comment: Right, I got that, sorry if my query was unclear.  I meant to ask what you want to do next, after you've read those 100 bytes past the half of the first line. (I assumed you want to keep reading from the file in some fashion.) Never mind, I posted what you asked (edited in the meanwhile). Clarify if needed.

Comment: Since you have already read the whole of the first line, why not just delete the first half of `$row` instead of re-reading the part you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you get the length of the line

```
my $row_len = length <$fh>;  # with newline, or (read then) chomp first
```

position the handle where you need it using [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)

```
use Fcntl qw(:seek);

seek $fh, $row_len/2, SEEK_SET;
```

where [Fcntl](http://perldoc.perl.org/Fcntl.html) provides constants `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR`, and `SEEK_END` so that the position in the second argument is taken from either the beginning, or the current position, or the end of file (when a negative position is normally used). Instead of these one can use `0`, `1`, `2`.

Then read `$bytes` into `$data` using [read](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html)

```
my $bytes = 100;
my $data;

my $rb = read $fh, $data, $bytes;
```

where `$rb` is how many bytes were actually read out of `$bytes` requested.

---

For some filehandles (sockets for one) `read` may not get as much as requested at once so you'd need to keep reading. For example, using `OFFSET` (see docs) at which to write to the string

```
use bytes qw();

my ($data, $requested, $total_read) = ('', 100, 0); 

while ($total_read < $requested) {
    my $bytes_data = bytes::length $data;
    $total_read += read $fh, $data, $requested - $bytes_data, $bytes_data;
}
```

where `read` now writes to `$data` at position `$bytes_data`. Without that offset each read overwrites `$data`, what can be appended to a string with all data (or otherwise accumulated).

While `bytes::length` is fine the [bytes pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/bytes.html) is in general "*strongly discouraged*".

---

Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments.

Note that `read` doesn't treat "newlines" in any special way and a read may well pick up from the next line(s) of the file, while those newline-bytes do count and thus affect your position in a file.

It is not specified what you want to do next but you can keep (repositioning and) reading.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16556468/4653379) for a crystal clear explanation of moving in a file with `seek` and `read`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that for some handles (sockets, at least), `read` might not read as many bytes as requested. A loop is needed.

Comment: Note that it's probably better to use named constants for the last (`WHENCE`) parameter of `seek`. So `use Fcntl ':seek'` and `seek $fh, $row_len/2, SEEK_SET`

Comment: @Borodin  Right ... I considered that and thought that it may spread the answer too wide.  I will add a bit on it, thank you.

Comment: @zdim: I can usually remember what zero does, but I can't use 1 or 2 correctly without checking the documentation!

Comment: `use Fcntl qw(:seek);` is not in the seek docs. It is not required and I don't accept that extra, un-rememberable lines of code and symbols are good, even if they are more orderly in your opinion. That's what your downvote is for.

Comment: @felwithe  Well, thanks for stating your reason for downvote, much appreciated. (1) It **is** in the docs -- did you look? -- right in the first paragraph of [seek](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek), loud and clear, and with the link to the module where constants (and the `:seek` tag) are given  (2) Module [Fcntl](https://perldoc.perl.org/Fcntl)  loads C's `Fcntl.h` defines, of the `fcntl(2)` fame, a standard utility for working with file descriptors (3) This way `seek` can use named constants of the `fseek(3)` syscall (4) This is widely considered good practice

Comment: @felwithe For future reference: fcntl == file control. I suggest to read through `Fcntl` docs to appreciate just how useful the module is, and for `fcntl` in general just type it in google and read down the page.